# can not see the contents of the template with directive

Tags: angularjs, html, angularjs-directive

I have a problem with the Directive, which does not add an element of Template.
This directive is included in the .html file.
The console does not display any error.

directive.js:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: '^ngModel',
    scope: {
        ngModel: '='
    },
    template: '<span>see this ? {{ ngModel }}</span>'
  }
});
```

html:

```
<div my-directive ng-model="content"></div>
```

I do not know why this is happening

Comment: Your template is missing a closing tag for span like so: <span>see this ? {{ ngModel }}</span>

Comment: Side note  - you should close your `<span>`

Comment: I escaped to write this post, but that does not change operation

Comment: put together a plunker, or have a working snippet, that would help.

Comment: You shouldn't use `ng-model`, unless you are building an input directive. And it works fine for me: http://plnkr.co/edit/AtPXvOToH9lMckL7uhaW?p=preview

Comment: yes but how do I eg. something like this:
$scope.content.more = "content";

and how it can get in the template directive ?template: '<span>see this ? {{ ngModel.more }}</span>'

Comment: @user3780659 why would you use `ngModel.more` to access the field `more` of the object called `content`? Wouldn't `content.more`be more logical?

Comment: sounds logical but does not work

Comment: @ribsies and another thank you very much for your help. Problem solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are using require: '^ngModel'

That doesn't do what you think it does.

require is used when you are nesting directives, or need to access a controller from another directive. For example, if you were making an accordian out of a list of items, you could have a directive called 'accordian-wrap' on the element that wraps the entire list and then a directive on each element called 'accordian-item'.

THEN, you would have something like this...

```
app.directive('accordianWrap', function() {
  return {
   restrict: 'A',
   template: 'template.html',
   controller: [function() {
   }]
  }
});

app.directive('accordianItem', function() {
  return {
   restrict: 'A',
   require: '^accordianWrap',
   template: 'template.html'
  }
});
```

Edit: I was mistaken on the use of require breaking it, it still works with require but in the case you are using it, it is not doing anything.

Edit: Plunker was being dumb, so here's a jsfiddle of it working, also with passing content into the directive.

http://jsfiddle.net/bhofuxeo/

Answer (score 0):

You added `require: '^ngModel'` that does mean directive parent element should contain `ng-model` attribute.

In your case it seems like you mistakenly added `^`. I believe it should be `require: '^ngModel'`

**Directive**

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    scope: {
        ngModel: '='
    },
    template: '<span>see this ? {{ ngModel }}</span>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl){ //ctrl is nothing but the ngModel ctrl

    }
  }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl" ng-init="content='Test'">
    <div my-directive ng-model="content"></div>
</div>
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w00eo4bz/5/)